# Change wc_empty_cart_message function in WooCommerce 3.1

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, notice

I've been trying to change my layout for the empty-cart message. I've removed the action, and try to replace it.

I'd like to change the htm structure output from:

```
<p class="empty-cart"></p>
```

to:

```
<div class="col-12 offset-md-1 col-md-10"><p class="empty-cart"></p></div>
```

My actual code *(in functions.php file of my theme)*:

```
/** Change the output for empty-cart within a div */
remove_action( 'wc_empty_cart_message', 'wc_empty_cart_message', 10 );
add_action( 'wc_empty_cart_message', 'wc_empty_cart_message', 10 );

function custom_wc_empty_cart_message() {
echo '<div class="col-12 offset-md-1 col-md-10"><p class="cart-empty">'
. wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'wc_empty_cart_message', __( 'Your cart is currently empty.', 'woocommerce' ) ) ) . '</p></div>';
}
```

But this code doesn't work. Does anyone has a suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here below is the correct way to make it work:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'wc_empty_cart_message', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'custom_empty_cart_message', 10 );

function custom_empty_cart_message() {
    $html  = '<div class="col-12 offset-md-1 col-md-10"><p class="cart-empty">';
    $html .= wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'wc_empty_cart_message', __( 'Your cart is currently empty.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
    echo $html . '</p></div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

To remove empty cart message use just:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'wc_empty_cart_message', 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks! @LoicTheAztec I've tried the code, but when i put it in my function.php i've got the following message: 
"Warning: Use of undefined constant html - assumed 'html' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/themes/Amplify/functions.php on line 172
html"

Comment: @OnnoV. Sorry I have a little mistake in my code. I have just updated it… Try it again please. It will work.

Comment: Can we add more then text? like     $html .= wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'wc_empty_cart_message', __( 'cart empty', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
    $html .= wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'wc_empty_cart_message', __( 'There is nothing in your cart, Lets add some items.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );

Comment: @user9437856 Try it yourself and you will have the answer… But the best thing is to use a unique text, so why you don't merge both texts in one?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. I have an h2 tag and p tag that the response I am using.